# Android Fabric : To add more events from the existing app (Answer)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fabric, fabric-answers

How to add new events on the existing app for Answers(Fabric) 
I did manage to add in the code part, but its not reflecting the Fabric dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to throw a fatal exception then use this.

```
public static void throwFatalException(Throwable throwable) {
        if (Fabric.isInitialized()) {
            Crashlytics.logException(throwable);
        }
    }
```

call method

```
throwFatalException(new Throwable(" My Message " + e));
```

Note: `FatalException` will not appear in the Dashboard instantly. it will take some time.